# Is it possible to unset all properties of an element except a certain one (e.g. the display property) using the all shorthand?

Tags: css

Is it possible to unset all properties of an element except a certain one (e.g. the display property) using the `all` shorthand?

```css
    button#text-button-1 {
      all: unset;
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<button id="text-button-1" class="hidden">Button</button>
```

Something like

```
button#text-button-1 {
      all:not(display): unset;
    }
```

(which is obviously wrong)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the all shorthand is unlike most shorthand in CSS in that it does not give you access to a long-hand version.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could have different cascade layers with different set properties and use the all shorthand with 'revert' or 'revert-layer' to access them.

Hope that helps!

G

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. But you actually didn't answer my question.

Comment: I have edited- hopefully it is better now- thanks!